# Create an instance in the main function

Tags: python, class

Here is my code from my`test.py` file

```
from Graph import *
def handleInput(fName):
    inputF = open(fileName, 'r')

    while(True):
        #initialize a graph
        g = Graph()
```

and in another file named `Graph.py` I have

```
from test.py import *
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
    self.vertices = {}
    self.numVertices = 0
    return
```

I am getting the error:

> global name Graph is not defined'

when I try to initialize a new graph, `g`, from the class `Graph`.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tried `g = Graph.Graph()`?

Comment: Use lowercase names for modules, to avoid confusion

Comment: You also seem to have circular dependency, importing file A in B and importing file B in A

Comment: Do your two modules import each other? Circular imports will get you in all kinds of trouble. EDIT, drat, too late :)

Comment: I tried g = Graph.Graph() and still got the same error

Comment: why are you importing test.py?

Comment: You don't get an `ImportError` on `test.py`?

Comment: Just for a case. Have you got a correct indentation in Graph.py file? There is a chance that your IDE is not telling you that the code in Graph.py -     self.vertices = {} an self.numVertices = 0 lines should be 4 spaces to the right therefore the class may be not compiled so it can't be imported. Otherwise you should fix your indentation here in the topic.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `test.py` it tries to import `Graph.py`, so `Graph.py` runs. When it runs, the first line is `from test import *` which again makes test run. The first line `from Graph import *` runs OK since python can eliminate circular dependencies and not re-import. But then you probably call something that calls `handleInput` which calls `g = Graph()`. But we're still importing `Graph.py`, remember? So we don't know what `Graph` is yet.

The best solution is remove the circular dependency if you don't need it, as Tim Castelijns offered.

If you for some reason need that dependency (you want to use `test.py` in `Graph.py`), you can put the code that makes `handleInput` run inside an:

```
if "__main__" == __name__:
    handleInput(...)
```

block.

To clarify what happens lets look at this code (This is `test.py`. I leave `Graph.py` untouched):

```
from Graph import *

def f():
    g = Graph()

print __name__    
if "__main__" == __name__:
    f()
```

When I run `python test.py`, it prints:

```
test
__main__
```

Why? Because when `Graph.py` imports `test.py`, its name is `"test"`. Only when it's done importing and `Graph` is finally defined, we move on to the original `test.py` run and the `__name__` becomes `"__main__"` again.